# how to change exported fbx image format?

Tags: export, .fbx

when im exported fbx file i need to change texture format because other program dont support .dds and support png and jpg images. Can someone help me please because if i found the solution it will save me much time!

Comment: I think Blender FBX exports images in `png` format along with objects.

Comment: How did you know blender exports in `.dds` image format?

Comment: my model has texture with dds texture and model xml